# Opening Files using Python in Prompt

Tags: python, windows

After invoking Python from within Windows Powershell, I am unable to open files in the current working directory.

```
PS C:\python27> python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

After that, I type:

```
 x = open(ex15_sample.txt)
```

With the idea of calling the open function on the filename parameter  of the text file I would like to open in Python. The idea is that I can then run the following code in Windows Powershell and open that file in Python through Powershell:

```
print x.read()
```

However I can't get to this step, because after I typed

```
x = open(ex15_sample.txt)
```

Powershell outputs the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ex15_sample' is not defined
```

In order to open the file "ex15_sample.txt" in Python via Powershell I also typed:

```
import ex15_sample.txt
```

After reading online that this can work, but Powershell outputted the following:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ex15_sample.txt
```

How can I open the file "ex15_sample.txt" from within Python via the Powershell Command Line Interface?

Comment: PowerShell's UI thread is suspended in the background at this point. Python inherits PowerShell's console window and does its own console input/output (I/O). It reads and writes to console buffer handles, which communicates with another process, conhost.exe, that actually manages the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty basic programming concept, and certainly not specific to Python. When you pass a value to a function like `open`, it can either be a variable containing a data, or a literal string. In this case, you want a string, and in most languages (including Python) strings must be surrounded by quotes:

```
x = open('ex15_sample.txt')
```

You've misunderstood what you've read about import: that's for loading other Python modules only.

Also note that none of this has anything to do with Powershell at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply open() with a string.

"ex15_sample.txt" is a string literal, but ex15_sample.txt is the name of a variable you haven't defined yet.

So, you would need to type

```
open("ex15_sample.txt")
```

Comment: I don't understand - I am quite new to this. What is a string literal? And what do you mean by "supply open() with a string"?

Comment: No problem! When you say `open(ex15_sample.txt)` Python looks for a variable named ex15_sample, and get its attribute txt. But there is no variable defined with that name! That's why you get the error. A string literal is just a collection of text. "ex15_sample.txt" is a string literal.

Comment: A string is a series of characters surrounded by double-quotes or single-quotes. For example, `"hello"` is a string, but `hello` is a variable. Notice the quotes. The `open()` function expects a string in between the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Think like this, when you run something, all the words in in it are commands (variables, functions, whatever), python will try to interpret all those things, when you try this:

```
open(ex15_sample.txt)
```

Python will effectively search for a command `open` (it will find, as it is a built-in function), and then it will search for another command `ex15_sample` that doesn't exist in python, so it will throw an error.

What you want to do is pass a text containing the name of the file to python, the way to do that is surrounding it with single or double quotes, either `'ex15_sample.txt'` or `"ex15_sample.txt"`, that way python interpret it as text instead of trying to understand it as a command, so

```
open('ex15_sample.txt')
```

is what you really want